# How to resolve exception org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException

Tags: java, json, cassandra

Kindly help me i am geting below exception when casting json string to java user defined object.

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "acknowledgedby" (Class com.xchange.model.XchangeOutboundMessage), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@3452296e; line: 1, column: 34] (through reference chain: com.xchange.model.XchangeOutboundMessage["acknowledgedby"])
```

i also found many link on here on stackoverflow and all recommends for @JsonIgnore annotation on field of model but i can't ignore this.

```
public List getOutBoundMessageList(){
        List list=new ArrayList();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        XchangeOutboundMessage xchangeOutboundMessage=null;
        String json1=null;
        try {

            cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(contactPoints).build();

            session = cluster.connect(keySpaceName);

            cassandraOps = new CassandraTemplate(session);
            String queryString="Select JSON * from XchangeOutboundMessage";
            ResultSet result = session.execute(queryString);
            int i=0;
            String json1=null;
            for(Row row:result) {
                json1 = row.getString(i);
                xchangeOutboundMessage = mapper.readValue(json1, XchangeOutboundMessage.class);
                list.add(xchangeOutboundMessage);
                i++;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Model class field and getter,setter where exception occuring

```
private String acknowledgedBy;
public String getAcknowledgedBy() {
        return acknowledgedBy;
    }
    public void setAcknowledgedBy(String acknowledgedBy) {
        this.acknowledgedBy = acknowledgedBy;
    }
```

Comment: suppose you share the whole Model class to get a clear understanding of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting Exception because of Jacks mapper is case sensitive.
By default cassandra make every column name tolowercase. That's why your  field name (acknowledgedBy) and cassandra cassandra's column name (acknowledgedby) not matching.

You can set jackson mapper to match key in case insensitive by configure method.

```
mapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
```